# TypeError: GroupedBy object is not subscriptable

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, typeerror

I have a dataset `df_1` that looks like this:

```
my_id        scope         feat_1     feat_2    value_1    value_2     value_3          date
23784    some_code          Three          A         30         60          60    2022-01-01
23794    some_code          Seven          B         60         40          20    2022-01-01
23774    some_cod1          Three          A         90         40          60    2022-01-02
22784    some_cod1          Three          C         30         10          60    2022-01-01
23564    some_cod2           Four          A         20         40          20    2022-01-05
20784    some_cod3           Five          A         10         70          40    2022-02-08
```

I need to perform a simple calculation on it, but since it updates quite often, I want to make sure that all the data is there. For that, I have the following guide `df_2`. `version` is always increasing and tells me when the newest update happened and I only care about the maximum `version` for a certain scope and date.

```
my_id        scope         feat_1     feat_2                   date     version
23784    some_code          Three          A             2022-01-01         600
23794    some_code          Seven          B             2022-01-01         600   
23774    some_cod1          Three          A             2022-01-02         600       
22784    some_cod1          Three          C             2022-01-01         650
23564    some_cod2           Four          A             2022-01-05         650
20784    some_cod3           Five          A             2022-02-08         700
20744    some_cod2           Five          A             2022-01-05         700
20745    some_cod2           Four          C             2022-01-05         700
```

I want to look at `df_2`, group by `scope` and `date` and get the maximum `version`, and then see if all `my_id`s are present in `df_1` for this version?

What I did:

```py
df_2 = df_2.groupBy(["date", "scope"])['version'].max()
df = df_1.join(df_2, on = ["my_id"], how = "leftanti")
```

But I get

> TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable

Why is that and is my logic incorrect?

Comment: that syntax is from pandas. pyspark equivalent would be `df_2.groupBy(["date", "scope"]).agg(func.max('version').alias('max_version'))` where `func` is the alias to `pyspark.sql.functions`

Comment: @samkart And then do the leftanti join like I did in my original post?

Comment: df_2 won't have `my_id` field as it was neither in the grouping fields nor in the aggregation fields. so, your join won't work unless you have the key in both dataframes. i think you should calculate the max of version using a window function. that way, the df_2 will have `my_id` as well as max version for a certain scope and date

Comment: @samkart Ah right, but then how do I "get back" to it, as in: now I know the maximum versions of interest, I know which my_id are supposed to be present in df_1, how do I do the actual check? I was thinking of just rebuilding df_2 with only the versions of interest and then do the antijoin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable

You get this error, because you do `.groupBy(["date", "scope"])['version']`.

`.groupBy(["date", "scope"])` returns an object of type `GroupedData`. With this object you try to do `['version']`. GroupedData object does not have a way to "access" elements using this syntax, i.e. no way to "subscribe" to any of its elements. This is why you get such error notice.

You could do what you want using window functions. E.g. calculate max 'version' over every window having the same 'scope' and 'date'. Then, `filter` on this max value and do the same "leftanti" join that you tried to do.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(23784, 'some_code', 'Three', 'A', 30, 60, 60, '2022-01-01'),
     (23794, 'some_code', 'Seven', 'B', 60, 40, 20, '2022-01-01'),
     (23774, 'some_cod1', 'Three', 'A', 90, 40, 60, '2022-01-02'),
     (22784, 'some_cod1', 'Three', 'C', 30, 10, 60, '2022-01-01'),
     (23564, 'some_cod2', 'Four', 'A', 20, 40, 20, '2022-01-05'),
     (20784, 'some_cod3', 'Five', 'A', 10, 70, 40, '2022-02-08')],
    ['my_id', 'scope', 'feat_1', 'feat_2', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'date'])
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(23784, 'some_code', 'Three', 'A', '2022-01-01', 60),
     (23794, 'some_code', 'Seven', 'B', '2022-01-01', 600),
     (23774, 'some_cod1', 'Three', 'A', '2022-01-02', 600),
     (22784, 'some_cod1', 'Three', 'C', '2022-01-01', 65),
     (23564, 'some_cod2', 'Four', 'A', '2022-01-05', 65),
     (20784, 'some_cod3', 'Five', 'A', '2022-02-08', 70),
     (20744, 'some_cod2', 'Five', 'A', '2022-01-05', 70),
     (20745, 'some_cod2', 'Four', 'C', '2022-01-05', 70)],
    ['my_id', 'scope', 'feat_1', 'feat_2', 'date', 'version'])
```

Script:

```py
w = W.partitionBy('scope', 'date').orderBy(F.desc('version'))
df_2 = (df_2
    .withColumn('max_version', F.first('version').over(w))
    .filter('version = max_version')
)
df = df_1.join(df_2, on=["my_id"], how="leftanti")

df.show()
# +-----+---------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
# |my_id|    scope|feat_1|feat_2|value_1|value_2|value_3|      date|
# +-----+---------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
# |23784|some_code| Three|     A|     30|     60|     60|2022-01-01|
# |23564|some_cod2|  Four|     A|     20|     40|     20|2022-01-05|
# +-----+---------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```